# Google Maps with follow-me

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create a google map application for pilots so the map centers on my position. The app must center the map on the position of the aircraft at a specific zoom level in order to display a buffer area of at least 5 nautical miles. The application must also provide two ways for follow-me:

- Track-App(it is the marker to rotate)
- North-App (it's the map to rotate)

For Track-App I calculate the boundbox

```
  protected LatLngBounds calcultateBoundBoxFollowMe(LatLng position, float distanceMiles){
        double distanceMeters = UnitConverter.convert(distanceMiles, UnitConverter.EConversionScalingFactor.NM_TO_MT, false);
        LatLngBounds.Builder l_0 = new LatLngBounds.Builder(  );
        l_0.include(CoordinateUtil.findLatLngtAtDistanceFrom(position, Math.toRadians(0), distanceMeters/1000)  );
        l_0.include(CoordinateUtil.findLatLngtAtDistanceFrom(position, Math.toRadians(90), distanceMeters/1000)  );
        l_0.include(CoordinateUtil.findLatLngtAtDistanceFrom(position, Math.toRadians(180), distanceMeters/1000)  );
        l_0.include(CoordinateUtil.findLatLngtAtDistanceFrom(position, Math.toRadians(270), distanceMeters/1000)  );
        return l_0.build();
    }
```

and use

```
googleMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(calcultateBoundBoxFollowMe(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()), DISTANCE_NAUTICAL_MILES),30));
```

For North-App I can't use the same function because I can't rotate the map, but I could use it

```
CameraPosition.Builder currentPlaceBuilder = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(currentLocation.getPosition().getCoordinate().y, currentLocation.getPosition().getCoordinate().x)).zoom(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom).bearing(orientationVals[0]);
```

but I don't know the zoom.

How can I calculate the zoom knowing that I have to see an area of at least 5 nautical miles around my position?

Comment: Why BoundBox like for Track-App is not acceptable?

Comment: because it is not possible to rotate the map.